# node moved between different container nodes has scene = nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, ios7.1

Here is a problem that I am having in Sprite Kit in iOS 7.1. It does not happen in iOS 8.1, so I am fairly certain it is a bug with 7.1, but I need a workaround to maintain compatibility.

I am removing a space ship sprite from a squadron container node, and then add it back to the scene. I turned on showsPhysics on the SKScene so that I could see what is going on. As soon as the ship breaks from the squadron the Physics debug display jumps all over the place, even though the ship appears to be in the correct position otherwise. It's not a bug with the debug display, unfortunately, because the detached physicsBody is now what is controlling the behavior. I can crash my own ship into the debug circle which is halfway across the screen from the detached enemy.

Here is where the problem starts:

```
-(void)breakFromSquadron{

CGPoint pos = [self positionInScene];
GameScene *scene = [self gameScene];

[self removeFromParent]; // removes ship from squadron (which is a child node of the node kWorldLayerShips, which is a child of the scene)

SKNode *layerNode = self.scene.layers[kWorldLayerShips]; 
[layerNode addChild:node]; // add ship directly as child of node layer 

self.position = pos;
```

}

Everything checks out when analyzing properties through these steps in the debugger, checking parents and the scene, but in the next update, if I check the scene (`po self.scene` in the debugger) the result is nil.

As I said, this is not a problem in iOS 8.1, just 7.1.

**[UPDATE]**
With the assistance of Apple Developer support, I now have a workaround. When removing the sprite from the container node, set a (boolean) flag indicating that the sprite needs to be removed. On the next update loop, check to see if the flag is set, remove it using [self removeFromParent] if so. Set another flag when it is ready to be added back, and again, on the update loop, add it back. The problems appeared to have been caused by these actions being triggered by a callback block, so they were happening outside of the main update loop in iOS 7.

Comment: I know this may not be an ideal solution (more like a potential workaround/hack), but maybe try creating a new SKPhysicsBody for the node before adding it to the layerNode.

Comment: It kind of seems like maybe there is an issue with changing coordinate systems in combination with a phsyics body. Maybe 8.x fixed that, but I'm thinking starting with a fresh phsyics body might be a valid solution.

Comment: @prototypical Thanks, but after searching for iOS 7.1 bugs, that was something I had tried. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: Have you tried creating a brand new node as well ? Also, are there any SKActions that might be running on that node at the time you do this switch? Or any references to the physicsBody somewhere else ? grasping at straws :)

Comment: @prototypical Creating a copy of the node using [self copy] doesn't seem to help, but creating a brand new node of course works, it's just a really expensive and kludgy work-around.... but thanks for the idea, it might be either do that or drop support for iOS 7.1 altogether.

Comment: Definitely not ideal. For the physics body, were you using copy ? or creating a new physics body ?

Comment: @prototypical Yes, creating new physicsBody. Even setting it to nil before removing it from parent, and waiting to add it again afterwards. It just occurred to me that it is possible that I am overriding something incorrectly, but it doesn't happen in iOS 8.1, whatever it is.

Comment: Do you use SKAction on these nodes at all ? The fact that a new node solves it, means there's still some kind of remnants in play with a copy, right ? Not sure what you are overriding, but certainly could be an issue.

Comment: @prototypical Possibly, but I am making sure to remove any with [self removeAllActions], shouldn't that do it?

Comment: Well, more specifically I was interested in runBlock actions that might have something in the block that has a different effect with a different parent node. It's also possible that switching coordinate systems while a SKAction that relies on position is in play might possibly have adverse effects.

Comment: I decided to use one of my developer support tickets to see if I can get Apple to figure it out.

Comment: I updated my original post to show the solution.

Comment: So your method above was not being called from the update loop ? was it called from an SKAction waitForDuration or something of that nature ?

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded a demonstration to github here: https://github.com/juggleware/SpriteKit7BugDemo

Comment: Makes all the difference. Good example of seeing more of the context of how that code is running might have narrowed it down quicker. Knowing it was being triggered from a SKAction block on the node is worth knowing :)

Comment: This has no answer right now, but worthwhile information. You should make an answer that gives a full scope of the issue and the workaround.